# 2 Column layout, how to apply border such that taller div dictates border height

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a two-column layout ... and the design requires a border dividing them. I'm confused, where to apply the border (to the left one) or the right one, but it needs to be dynamic depending on which has more content.

Do I have to resort to a container div? Does somebody have an example? I'm trying to adapt examples of backgrounds to do this, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure if i understood the question right.

But i would do it like this

```
div container
+ div left content
+ div right content
+ div line
```

By setting the line absolute and the container relative. So you can give the line a left position of 50% and a height of 100% so its always as long as the content.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ej2Gy/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jzsQh/

Fairly simple:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .left-column, .right-column {
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .left-column {
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .right-column {
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
        margin-left: -1px;  // makes the borders line up
    }
    .clearfix {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

<!-- Example: Longer Left Column -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-column">
        Longer Left Content<br>
        Longer Left Content<br>
        Longer Left Content<br>
        Longer Left Content<br>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
        Shorter Right Content<br>
        Shorter Right Content<br>
    </div>
    <br class="clearfix">
</div>

<!-- Example: Longer Right Column -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-column">
        Shorter Left Content<br>
        Shorter Left Content<br>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
        Longer Right Content<br>
        Longer Right Content<br>
        Longer Right Content<br>
        Longer Right Content<br>
    </div>
    <br class="clearfix">
</div>
```